# How to create dash rounded circle image view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to create this type of design for my profile page but I really don't know how to create the dashed circle in a flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a rounded image or rounded container and then use this plugin `dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dotted Border'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                spacing: 8,
                children: <Widget>[
                  rectBorderWidget,
                  roundedRectBorderWidget,
                  customBorder,
                  roundStrokeCap,
                  solidBorder,
                  fullWidthPath,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Draw a border with rectangular border
  Widget get rectBorderWidget {
    return DottedBorder(
      dashPattern: [8, 4],
      strokeWidth: 2,
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 120,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Draw a border with a rounded rectangular border
  Widget get roundedRectBorderWidget {
    return DottedBorder(
      borderType: BorderType.RRect,
      radius: Radius.circular(12),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 120,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Draw a border with custom path border
  Widget get customBorder {
    Path customPath = Path()
      ..moveTo(20, 20)
      ..lineTo(50, 100)
      ..lineTo(20, 200)
      ..lineTo(100, 100)
      ..lineTo(20, 20);

    return DottedBorder(
      customPath: (_) => customPath,
      color: Colors.indigo,
      dashPattern: [8, 4],
      strokeWidth: 2,
      child: Container(
        height: 220,
        width: 120,
        color: Colors.green.withAlpha(20),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Set border stroke cap
  Widget get roundStrokeCap {
    return DottedBorder(
      dashPattern: [8, 4],
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
      borderType: BorderType.RRect,
      radius: Radius.circular(5),
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 120,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get solidBorder {
    return DottedBorder(
      dashPattern: [4, 3],
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 200,
        width: 120,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get fullWidthPath {
    return DottedBorder(
      customPath: (size) {
        return Path()
          ..moveTo(0, 20)
          ..lineTo(size.width, 20);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**Or try this**

```
dashed_circle: ^0.0.2

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dashed_circle/dashed_circle.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg/2560px-Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dashed Circle Example',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: DashedCircle(
            child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]